# Using peak and lock patter inside Azure Trigger function for service bus topic in java(maven)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-triggers

How can I implement the Peek and Lock pattern within the ServiceBusTopicTrigger in Azure Functions without creating a new receiver for receiving messages? I have an Azure Function that successfully receives messages from the Service Bus Topic, but the problem is that the service automatically deletes the messages. I need to process the messages based on the quantity and either complete or abandon them. How can I achieve this using the Peek and Lock pattern without creating a new receiver within the function?

```
// This is my azure function

public class ServiceBusTopicTriggerJava {

  /**
   * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the Service Bus Topic.
   */
  @FunctionName("ServiceBusTopicTriggerJava")
  public void run(
      @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
          name = "message",
          topicName = "aftopic",
          subscriptionName = "afSubscription",
          connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString"
      ) final List<Sales> message,
      final ExecutionContext context
  ) {
//log go here

  }
```

```
This is my pojo data
@Data
@Builder
public class Sales {

  private String id;
  private String itemId;
  private String itemName;
  private double quantity;
  private double price;

}
```

```
// this is my message from service bus

[{"id":"6a2a7d07-1b0c-48db-9753-3f32d619ebd5","itemId":"123","itemName":"Item 123","quantity":35.0,"price":10.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is peek-lock itself, but it is tied to the successful execution of your function. If the function succeeds, the message is completed and otherwise is tried until the configured `maxRetries` value in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3#hostjson-settings).

In C#, you can bind to the `MessageReceiver` instance but unfortunately this isn't possible for non-C# languages. Even if you were to build the receiver instance, you can't complete/abandon the message since the lock token isn't available to the function.

The workaround here would be to instead create a new message for failures into a different queue to schedule work for the future. This is like what dead lettering looks like except that you would use a queue managed by you instead of the dead letter sub queue.

Also, there is [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5252) that tracks this but hasn't seen any traction.